# Scan set of integers into 2-D array

Tags: arrays, c

Consider the following set of numbers:

```
10 20 30
11 31 45
...
```

I want to define a 2-D array `int_array[][3]` such that `int[0]` contains `{10, 20, 30}`, then `int[1]` contains `{11, 31, 45}` and so on.

Assume that these values are in a file. The code I would use is therefore:

```
int int_array[NUM_ROWS][3], i;

for (i=0; i<NUM_ROWS;i++)
    fscanf(filePointer, "%d", int_array[i]);
```

However, this produces ridiculous results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `int_array[i]` A 2d array needs 2 indexes. For example: `fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d %d", &int_array[i][0], &int_array[i][1], &int_array[i][2]);`

Comment: But what about a string? if instead of being integers, each row was a set of characters, then `fscanf(filePointer, "%d", char_array[i])` would scan the whole string and everything works correctly... is this only applicable for strings?

Comment: And yes, I am aware of the way you suggested, however, my real set of numbers does not have 3 columns but instead multiple. I wanted to find a more efficient way to scan rather than write %d ten times.

Comment: Use 2 loops: `for (int row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) { for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {  fscanf(filePointer, "%d", &int_array[row][column]); }}`

Comment: That means I'll have to reset the cursor each time, no? because every new `fscanf` starts reading from a new line. Also, is there no way to fill array like I would for a string? Is this just a difference between character arrays and non character arrays that I must simply accept and move on? Thank you for all your replies.

Comment: _fscanf starts reading from a new line._ That is not true. With `%d` it will stop scanning when it reaches a non-digit. That can be a space, newline, whatever.

Comment: Right, thank you. And about the character scanning?

Comment: If you are referring the fact that you can use `%s` to put a sequence of chars in an array, then that is different. It's kind of a special case and you can't do that for numbers.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was referring to. Thank you.

Comment: What is `NUM_ROWS`?  Does the input file have exactly `NUM_ROWS` lines of data?

Answer (score 1):

> produces ridiculous results. What am I doing wrong?

- `int_array[i]` points to only 1 `int`, not the 3 needed.
- Code lacks error checking.

---

Create a helper function to read 1 line of data, saving the data when `d != NULL`.

```
int read3int(FILE *inf, int d[3]) {
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, inf) == NULL) {
    return EOF;
  }
  int n = 0;
  int i[3];
  sscanf(buf, "%d%d%d %n", &i[0], &i[1], &i[2], &n);
  // Was scan incomplete or with extra junk?
  if (n == 0 || buf[n] != 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (d) {
    d[0] = i[0];
    d[1] = i[1];
    d[2] = i[2];
  }
  return 1;
}
```

To form the array, first find how many rows.

```
size_t rows = 0;
while (read3int(filePointer, NULL) > 0) {
  rows++;
}

// Form the array
int data[rows][3]; // VLA or use malloc

// Rewind !!
rewind(filePointer);
for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  if (read3int(filePointer, data[r]) < = 0) {
    // Unexpected 2nd pass inconsistency
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said in the comments: "my real set of numbers does not have 3 columns but instead multiple"

I am posting a general method to read lines of integers from a file, storing them in a 2D array. It works regardless of the number of integers in each line.

But I haven't run this piece of code and I never used `strtol`, so chances are it doesn't work. I am giving you the idea, you can implement it properly.

```
char line[N], *ptr;

for(i = 0; fgets(line, N, filePointer) != NULL; i++) {
    
    int_array[i][0] = (int) strtol(line, &ptr, 10);
    
    for(j = 1; *ptr != '\n'; j++) {
        
        int_array[i][j] = (int) strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
    }
}
```

The logic is to read an entire line as a string and then convert the numbers from `char` to `int`.